# C# accessors and object class inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, accessor

So I have a maybe naive question about object inheritance and constructors. Basically, a class has an object:

```
public class ParentClass{
protected Parent item;
```

And the accessor goes as follows:

```
public Parent ItemValue
{
    set
    {
        item = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Now I want to inherit the class:

```
public class ChildClass:ParentClass
    {
    public new Child item;
    }
```

Now, whenever I access the `Child item` through the inherited accessor it, of course, returns the item as the `Parent` class instead of `Child` class. Is there a way to make it return the `item` as `Child` class without overwriting the accessor in the `ChildClass`?

Comment: No offense, but your terms are all wrong. For instance what do you mean by _return the child class_?

Comment: If you *have to* know that `ItemValue` is `Child` instead of `Parent`, then you aren't doing OOP right. Please show what exactly you want to do

Comment: Hope I fixed it; I meant I want to access the `item` via the `ChildClass` inherited accessor and return it as `Child` class object, not `Parent` class object

Comment: Maybe, but without a "why I need to" it seems like an odd question. For example a dog class, inheriting from animal. Why would you want `Dog.Speak` to do anything a dog would not do?

Comment: Are you trying to do polymorphism, similar method with different implementations?

Comment: Also, notice that `new` effectively hides the inherited property/field, and it's not common to use it. I'd suggest you to do some basic tests (with `Console.WriteLine`)

Comment: I'm building a inheritance tree, and the `item` object will be of different classes on different inheritance level. Now I want to build methods operating for specific levels and they need to access different properties of the `item`, depending on the level they are accessing.

Comment: What is Parent vs ParentClass and Child vs ChildClass. The relationship for what you're doing isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't change type of base property to return different (derived) type.

Standard workaround if you don't need inheritance - generic class:

```
public class ParentClass<T> {
      public T ItemValue { get; set; }
...
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass<ChildClass> 
{
  ...
}
```

Note that if you just need access to item in its own class you can just have `virtual` property:

```
public class Parent { }
public class Child:Parent { public string ChildProperty; }

public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public abstract Parent ItemValue { get; }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    Child item;
    public override Parent ItemValue { get {return item;} }

    public void Method()
    {
       // use item's child class properties
       Console.Write(item.ChildProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I guess that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to have Item of a type defined by your descendent class, you can do this

```
public class ParentClass<T>{
  protected T item;
  public T ItemValue
  {
    set
    {
        item = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return item;
    }
  }
}

public class ChildClass:ParentClass<Child>
{
    // No need to create a new definition of item
}
```

However depending on your problem, your next question will be how can I add ChildClass1 and ChildClass2 to the same List/Array/Dictionary/etc when they have different T's.

Take a step back for a minute. Does your ParentClass really need to know what item is?

(Ab)Using the Animal example above, your Horse might have a Walk(), Trot(), Canter() or Gallop() methods but a Duck might have a Swim() or Waddle() methods.

Perhaps your logic says something like, iterate my animal collection and tell the swimmers to swim. In this case, you could declare:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public class Location {}

    public interface ISwimmer{
      void SwimTo(Location destination);
    }

    public class Animal {} // whatever base class properties you need

    public class Duck : Animal, ISwimmer
    {
        public void SwimTo(Location destination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Implement duck's swim logic");           
        }
    }

    public class Fish : Animal, ISwimmer
    {
        public void SwimTo(Location destination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Implement fish's swim logic");
        }
    }

    public class Giraffe : Animal {}


    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>
        {
            new Duck(),
            new Fish(),
            new Giraffe()
        };  

        foreach (Animal animal in animals)
        {
            ISwimmer swimmer = animal as ISwimmer;          
            if (swimmer==null) continue; // this one can't swim
            swimmer.SwimTo(new Location());
        }
    }
}
```